# How to get "Sent Mail" as a navigation tab on Left nav bar in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, navigation

How to get "Sent Mail" as a navigation tab on Left nav bar in microsoft Outlook 2007? I have inbox, unread mail , calendar etc but I badly want "Sent Mail". All the time I need to go to Navigation Pane and then select sent mail. I need it right on the bar like the inbox and unread mail.

I am using outlook exchange server at office.

Comment: What type of account do you use (POP3/IMAP/Hotmail/Exchange/...)?

Comment: i'm using exchange server at office.

Comment: Are you sure your system administrator didn't disable this folder?

Comment: yes its not disabled.